# runing pyspark on my windows system ocurred Py4JJavaError

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running pyspark on my win10 system, when using `counts.saveAsTextFile("wc")` it went wrong

I've set environment variables of JAVA ，Hadoop，scala，winutils，on my laptop，

```py
counts.saveAsTextFile("wc")
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o125.saveAsTextFile.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
```

Comment: Check the version of Java being used. Incase you have 1.9 installed, downgrade it to Java 1.8 and then try. It might solve the issue.

Comment: I installed jdk1.8.0_202. It does not seem to be the problem